# BufferReader stuck in readline()

Tags: java, http

I am making an HTTP server and HTTP web client for simple Http request and response.

This is the code for Server

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public final class WebServer{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    //storing port number
    int port = 2048;

    //open socket and wait for TCP connection

    ServerSocket serverConnect = new ServerSocket(port);
    System.out.println("Server started.\nListening for connections on port : " + port + " ...\n");

        // we listen until user halts server execution
    while (true) {
        //Construct an object to process the HTTP request message. 
        //This will call another class where we do everything else
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(serverConnect.accept());

        //create a new thread to process the request
        Thread thread = new Thread(request);
        thread.start();

    } //end of while

}//end of main
}//end of the class webServer
```

The code for HttpRequest class is as follow:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

final class HttpRequest implements Runnable{

final static String CRLF = "\r\n";
Socket socket;  

//start of constructor
public HttpRequest(Socket socket) throws Exception{

    this.socket=socket;
}//end of constructor

//Implement the run() method of the Runnable interface.
public void run(){

    try{
        processRequest();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}//end of run

private void processRequest() throws Exception{

    //Get a reference to the scoket's input and output streams.
    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

    //set up the stream filters
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    //Get the request line of the HTTP request message.
    String requestLine = br.readLine();

    //Display the request line
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(requestLine);

    //Get and display the header lines.

    String headerLine = null;
        while((headerLine = br.readLine()).length()!=0){
            System.out.println(headerLine);
        }
        //System.out.println(requestLine);

    //Extract the filename from the request line.
    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(requestLine);
    tokens.nextToken(); //skip over the method, which should be. "GET"
    String fileName = tokens.nextToken();

    //Prepend a "." so that file request is within the current directory
    fileName = "." + fileName;
    //printing for test
    //System.out.println(fileName);

    //Open the requested file
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    boolean fileExists = true;
    try{
        fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        fileExists = false;
    }

    //Construct the response message
    String statusLine = null;
    String contentTypeLine = null;
    String entityBody = null;

    if(fileExists){
        statusLine = tokens.nextToken();
        contentTypeLine = "Content-type: " + contentType(fileName) + CRLF;
    }
    else{
        statusLine = "HTTP/1.1 404 File Not Found";
        contentTypeLine =  "Content-type: " + "text/html" + CRLF;
        entityBody = "<html><head><title>Not Found </title></head>" +
                     "<BODY>Not Found</body></html>";
    }

    //send the status line
    os.writeBytes(statusLine);

    //send the content Type
    os.writeBytes(contentTypeLine);

    //send a blank line to indicate the end of the header lines
    os.writeBytes(CRLF);

    //send the entity Body

    if(fileExists){
        sendBytes(fis, os);
        fis.close();
    }
    else{
        os.writeBytes(entityBody);
        os.writeBytes(CRLF);

    }

    //Close scokets and streams.
    fis.close();
    os.close();
    br.close();
    socket.close();

}//end of processRequest

private static String contentType(String fileName){
    if(fileName.endsWith(".htm") || fileName.endsWith(".html")){
        return "text/html";
    }
    if(fileName.endsWith(".gif")){
        return "image/gif";
    }
    if(fileName.endsWith(".jpeg") || fileName.endsWith(".jpg")){
        return "image/jpeg";
    }
    return "application/octet-stream";
}// end of contentType

private static void sendBytes(FileInputStream fis, OutputStream os) throws Exception{
    //Construct a 1k buffer to hold bytes on their way to the Socket

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytes = 0;

    //Copy requested file into the scoket's output stream.
    while((bytes = fis.read(buffer)) != -1){
        os.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
    }//end of while
}//end of sendBytes


} // end of the class
```

The Code works fine when I make a request from Chrome webbrowser. However, I made WebClient as well. When I make request from WebClient, I am stuck as the program runs forever.

As far I have tracked, the pointer does not move from the br.readline on the while loops on the Server Side.

The code for my client is as follow.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class WebClient{

final static String CRLF = "\r\n";

public static void main(String [] args) {
  String serverName = args[0];
  int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
  try {
     // System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName + " on port " + port);
     Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);

     System.out.println("Just connected to " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
     OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
     DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

     out.writeUTF("GET /" +args[2] +" HTTP/1.1");
     out.writeUTF(CRLF);
     out.writeUTF("Host: "+client.getLocalSocketAddress());
     out.writeUTF(CRLF);   
     out.writeUTF("Connection: close" + CRLF);
     out.writeUTF("User-agent: close" + CRLF);
     out.writeUTF(CRLF);  

    //Cache-Control: max-age=0


     System.out.println("Just connected to 1 ");      
     InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
              System.out.println("Just connected to 2 "); 
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inFromServer));
              System.out.println("Just connected to 3 ");
     String headerLine = null;
     while((headerLine = br.readLine()).length()!=0){
            System.out.println("asd"+headerLine);
        }
      System.out.println("Just connected to 4 ");
     client.close();
      System.out.println("Just connected to 5 ");


  } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

}

```
}//end of the class WebClient
```

Can anyone help me figure out the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to remove line `fis.close();` (right before `os.close();`) in your `HttpRequest` class: if no file exists, this line raises `NullPointerException` because `fis` is null, so after sending `Not Found` response to the browser, your server does not close the socket accepted from that browser, that's why even though you see `Not Found` in your browser, your request never ends.

Secondly, the reason of why your client gets stuck is `writeUTF()` method that you used for sending request header. Seems that this line `out.writeUTF(CRLF);` does not really send an empty string but adds some other UTF-related character(s) (you may notice that in your server's console output), so your server gets stuck at `while((headerLine = br.readLine()).length()!=0)` waiting for the client to send an empty string, but never receives it. You need to replace `out.writeUTF(CRLF);` with `out.writeBytes(CRLF);`.

Also, it makes little sense to use `BufferedReader` for receiving binary files from socket. `Reader` in general is used with character-input stream, so it is not applicable for your case. You may use `InputStream` instead, by replacing this fragment:

```
String headerLine = null;
     while((headerLine = br.readLine()).length()!=0){
            System.out.println("asd"+headerLine);
        }
```

with this (I chose buffer size of 4096, you may replace it with your preferred value):

```
 int readBytes;
 byte[] cbuf = new byte[4096];
 while((readBytes=inFromServer.read(cbuf, 0, 4096))>-1){
        System.out.println("read: " + readBytes);
    }
```

Note: You may easily notice here that `InputStream.read()` will fetch not only the file itself but also `statusLine`, `contentTypeLine` and two `CRLF`s, so in case if you would like to separate them from the file, you may read them first, by issuing two "readLines" and then fetch the file only by `read()`

Answer (score 1):

In your server, you use [`writeBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeBytes(java.lang.String))

> Writes out the string to the underlying output stream as a sequence of bytes. Each character in the string is written out, in sequence, by discarding its high eight bits. If no exception is thrown, the counter written is incremented by the length of s.

While you may worry about non-ASCII text, generally this is what you need.

In your client you attempt to use [`writeUTF()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF(java.lang.String))

> ***First, two bytes are written to the output stream as if by the writeShort method giving the number of bytes to follow. This value is the number of bytes actually written out, not the length of the string. Following the length***, each character of the string is output, in sequence, using the modified UTF-8 encoding for the character. If no exception is thrown, the counter written is incremented by the total number of bytes written to the output stream. This will be at least two plus the length of str, and at most two plus thrice the length of str.

While that 2-byte length in the beginning can be useful in other cases, it is not what web servers expect, including yours (and that is correct). So use `writeBytes()` everywhere in your client, and it will suddenly work:

```
 out.writeBytes("GET /" +args[2] +" HTTP/1.1");
 out.writeBytes(CRLF);
 out.writeBytes("Host: "+client.getLocalSocketAddress());
 out.writeBytes(CRLF);
 out.writeBytes("Connection: close" + CRLF);
 out.writeBytes("User-agent: close" + CRLF);
 out.writeBytes(CRLF);
```

---

In fact those extra bytes may be visible in your server output, at least when I ran it in Eclipse, I saw garbage characters, as a combination of mysterious empty space and a tiny question mark in a rectangle (note how they also appear at the end of the lines when CRLF is sent separately):

[image]

(The first request is the one issued with `writeUTF`, and the second one comes from Chrome)